# Divide triangle into two equivalent parts by line perpendicular to the base.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Originally the problem wants me to divide into 3 equivalent(equal areas) parts but I thought that I should do 2 first. Tried 2 and could not after many attempts. DF below is movable so it is not really the correct solution.

[image]

Comment: For those who are wondering about my figure. I was thinking of starting starting with angle CBA and set up random point F (final figure will be scaled later on). Erect perpendicular on F to find D. F is actually mid point of BE so mark E. Why construct E? If a point A could be found such that EA and DC is parallel, and CA is parallel to the orginal "CA" of the triangle then poly CEAD is a trapezoid. The triangles adjacent to the sides formed by the diagonas of trapezoid is equiv so from the isosceles ADE we can construct a triangle ABC similar to the original, and in both triangles DF divides.

Comment: Taking the proportions of BF to FC then the original triangle also divided similarly. The problem is after marking E: finding A such that that condition holds.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm too lazy to draw a figure. Therefore I use coordinates to fix ideas. Nevertheless the solution is not in terms of analytic geometry.)

Assume $B=(0,0)$, $F=(x,0)$, $C=(c,0)$, and $A=(p,q)$ with ${c\over2}\leq p\leq c$. We then want
$${1\over2}\  x\cdot{q\over p}x={1\over2}\ {c q\over2}\ ,$$
or
$$x^2={1\over2}\>cp\ .$$
Since $x$ is independent of $q$ we may replace $A$ by $A=(p,q')$ such that the resulting triangle has a right angle at $A'$ (draw a Thales circle over $BC$ to find $A'$). Letting $|BA'|=:s$ we have $cp=s^2$, by "Euclid's theorem". We therefore have to divide $s$ by $\sqrt{2}$ in order t obtain $x$. Constructively this can be done by drawing a square with side $s$ and taking half the diagonal.

Use similar ideas to divide the given triangle into three parts of equal area.

Comment: Do not now how this "@" here. Hahaha.I am usually apprehensive about using coordinates but this is it. An application of your result: http://imgur.com/a/dRbmf

Answer (score 0):

### The Math

[image]

\begin{align}
\text {Area of }\triangle \text{ ABH} &= \frac{mbh}{2} \\[1.5ex]
\text {Area of }\triangle \text{ AXY} &= \frac{mx^2}{2} \\[1.5ex]
\text{For } \triangle \text { AXY to be half the area of } \triangle { ABH:} \\[1.5ex]
\frac{mx^2}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{mbh}{2} \\[1.5ex]
\text{giving } x \text{ (independent of gradient } m \text{)}: \\[1.5ex]
x^2 &= \frac{bh}{2}\\ 
x &= \sqrt{\frac{bh}{2}}
\end{align}

#### The Construction

[image]
1. Draw a line $\perp$ to AC through A, and a line $\parallel$ to AC through B. Mark D, the point of intersection.
[image]
2. Mark E, the midpoint of AC. Then with centre A and radius AE, draw a circle. Mark F, the point of intersection of the circle and the perpendicular.

\begin{align}
\text{DF} &= \text{AD} + \text{AF} = h \text{ (height)} + \frac{b \text{ (base)}}{2}
\end{align}

[image]

3. Mark G, the midpoint of DF. Then with centre G and radius DG, draw a circle cutting AC in H.
   AH = $\sqrt{\frac{bh}{2}}$, which is the required length (see Note 1 below).

[image]

4. Draw the line $\perp$ to AC through H, cutting AB in I.

[image]

5. $\triangle$ AHI is half the area of $\triangle$ ABC

[image]

---

**Notes:**

1. In step 3 above,

   \begin{align}
   \text {AD } & = h \\
   \text {AF } & = \frac{b}{2} \\[1.5ex]
   \text {DG } & = \frac{h + \frac{b}{2}}{2} = \frac{h}{2} + \frac{b}{4} \\[1ex]
   \text {So, AG} &= h - (\frac{h}{2} + \frac{b}{4}) = \frac{h}{2} - \frac{b}{4}  \\[1ex]  
   \text {And, GH} & = DG = \frac{h + \frac{b}{2}}{2} = \frac{h}{2} + \frac{b}{4} \\[1ex]
   \text{Now, let AH } &= x \\[1ex]
   \text{Then by Pythagoras' Theorem (} \triangle \text{AGH):} \\
   x^2 & = (\frac{h}{2} + \frac{b}{4})^2 - (\frac{h}{2} + \frac{b}{4})^2 \\[1ex]
         & = \frac{bh}{2} \\
   \text{And, } x &= \sqrt{\frac{bh}{2}}
   \end{align}